# PHP search string on stored int

Tags: php, search, pdo

I am trying to develop a search function for my web page.
Some of the columns in the database are stored as integers representing values.
I have a function to display these when returning results:

```
public function listsystypestatus($sysobj){

if ($this->sysobj ==='1') return "Core";
if ($this->sysobj ==='2') return "Aggregation";
if ($this->sysobj ==='3') return "Core/Aggr";
if ($this->sysobj ==='4') return "Customer";
if ($this->sysobj ==='5') return "TX Site";
return "--Please Select--";
```

I want to be able to search on this column and return results.
eg wildcard search on "Cus" and return all records that are stored as "4" in the db for this column.
I have no idea how I can approach this.

My search query works for other (string) fields:

```
if($action=='search' && $search!=NULL){ 


 $wildsearch = "%%$search%%";
    $query = "SELECT *, INET_NTOA(ip_add) AS ip_add
    FROM `equipment` 
    LEFT JOIN itam_asset on equipment.itamname=itam_asset.ASSETID 
    WHERE site_code LIKE :search 
    OR site_id LIKE :search 
    OR system_name LIKE :search 
    OR INET_NTOA(ip_add) LIKE :search 
    OR sys_loc LIKE :search 
    OR systype LIKE :search 
    OR itamname LIKE :search 
    OR dimetis LIKE :search 
    OR DNS LIKE :search 
    ";

//Get equipment data
//select and prepare
$database->query($query);
//Bind
$database->bind(':search',$wildsearch);
  }else{
   ....
   ....
   Display results
```

The code I use to display the returned results is:

```
<?php
foreach($rows as $row){

//extract row
//this will make $row['firstname'] to
//just $firstname only
extract($row);
...
...
echo reults
...
...
```

Thanks to all.

EDIt:
New query - Now works:

```
$query = "SELECT *, INET_NTOA(ip_add) AS ip_add, list_systype.systype_label 
        FROM `equipment` 
        LEFT JOIN itam_asset on equipment.itamname=itam_asset.ASSETID 
        LEFT JOIN list_systype on equipment.systype=list_systype.systype_value
        WHERE site_code LIKE :search 
        OR site_id LIKE :search 
        OR system_name LIKE :search 
        OR INET_NTOA(ip_add) LIKE :search 
        OR sys_loc LIKE :search 
        OR list_systype.systype_label LIKE :search 
        OR itamname LIKE :search 
        OR dimetis LIKE :search 
        OR DNS LIKE :search 
        ";
```

Comment: If you keep the id->string association in PHP, then you'll have to search through those yourself and issue the SQL query with any resulting int. Else move your id->string list to the database, in a separate table, and do a JOIN on those int columns for searching.

Comment: Thanks. I modified query above and now works great :)....Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, you want to search for the "4" if you search for "Cus" because "4" is "Customer" in your `listsystypestatus` function. To do so you need:

1. Look for the status that matches, and find out the number associated to it
2. Look for the relevant entry in the database based on that integer

On subject 2, you can probably just restrict the query to search for the sysobj field.

I would rewrite your `listsystypestatus` logic a bit, so you can reuse it for the search.

```
class Test {

  // Your type
  private $systypes = array('1' => 'Core', '2' => 'Aggregation', '3' => 'Core/aggr', '4' => 'Customer', '5' => 'TX Site');

  public function listsystypestatus($sysobj) {
    var_dump(array_key_exists($sysobj, $this->systypes));
    if(array_key_exists((int)$sysobj, $this->systypes)) {
      return $this->systypes[$sysobj];
    }
    return "--Please Select--";
  }

  // Retrieve the type
  public function gettype($search) {
    $matches = array_filter($this->systypes, function($text) use ($search) {
        return ( strpos($text, $search) !== false );
    });

    return array_keys($matches);
  }
}

$test = new Test();

// Retrieving records for 'Cus' (only one, 4)
var_dump($test->gettype('Cus'));

// Few more hits now
$result = $test->gettype('C');
var_dump(implode(',', $result));
```

With the resulting array you can decide what you want to do in your SQL Query. For example, do an IN(1,2,3) for all the values in the array or something similar.

Comment: Of course, if you can solve that in the database, that is likely to be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks for feed back - I'm still trying to get my head around OOP in general. I haven't had time to work through your suggestions, but they look very useful. I will be implementing them when I get a chance. BTW I fixed my search problem by having a separate table and doing a join as suggested by Mario

Comment: If you consider this answer useful, please accept the answer. Thanks!